# Unable to install PyArrow on cdsw

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, pyarrow

I am trying to run below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

# create sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 0.00),
    (2, -1.23),
    (3, 4.56),
], ['id', 'value'])


# define your custom Pandas UDF
@pandas_udf('double')
def probnorm(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(norm.cdf(s))


# create a new column using the Pandas UDF
df = df.withColumn('pnorm', probnorm(F.col('value')))
```

Error mess :

```
ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.8.0 must be installed; however, it was not found.
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
in engine
      1 @pandas_udf('double')
----> 2 def probnorm(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
      3     return pd.Series(norm.cdf(s))

/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _create_udf(f, returnType, evalType)
     45 
     46         from pyspark.sql.utils import require_minimum_pyarrow_version
---> 47         require_minimum_pyarrow_version()
     48 
     49         argspec = _get_argspec(f)

/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in require_minimum_pyarrow_version()
    147     if not have_arrow:
    148         raise ImportError("PyArrow >= %s must be installed; however, "
--> 149                           "it was not found." % minimum_pyarrow_version)
    150     if LooseVersion(pyarrow.__version__) < LooseVersion(minimum_pyarrow_version):
    151         raise ImportError("PyArrow >= %s must be installed; however, "

ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.8.0 must be installed; however, it was not found
```

I have Python 3.6 version; and have tried Pyarrow version from 5.0 to 1.0. I have linux OS.
Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: cdsw@dumuser:~/Package$ python3 -m pip install pyarrow-3.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl pyarrow-3.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I do not know much about cdsw but do you know what version of pip you have installed?  Older versions of pip (older than `19.0`) will report `is not a supported wheel on this platform` for manylinux2010 wheels.